# HTML Layout : Continuous images

Tags: html, css

I have a series of images, which I want to make them showing in a row, i.e.

> [img][img][img][img][img][img][img][img][img][img][img][img][img][img][img]

I want the overflow part will be hidden.

My current HTML is as follow:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" class="gallery_img" />
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg" class="gallery_img" />
  <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" class="gallery_img" />
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg" class="gallery_img" />
  <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" class="gallery_img" />
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg" class="gallery_img" />
  <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" class="gallery_img" />
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg" class="gallery_img" />
  <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" class="gallery_img" />
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
#gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#gallery .gallery_img {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/HP3h8/). I would like to show half image in the edge of the screen, like this:

[image]

However, I can only manage to show full images only. How should I modify the HTML / CSS codes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use overwidth in percentage, and a mask div:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jQkHp/3/)

```
#gallery {  
  width: 200%; /* this is the trick */
}
#gallery img {   /* and no need to add class="gallery_img" to IMGs anymore */
  height: 200px;
}

#wrapper {  
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}



<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="gallery">
    <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" />    
    <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" />    
    <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" />        
    <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" />        
    <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" />        
    <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" />        
    <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" />        
    <img src="http://www.o2h.com.hk/images/apple_gala.JPG" />        
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

I'll add the simplest solution too (posted by @RupaliShinde), because it shows the correct use of the `white-space` attribute, and appearently it is hard to reproduce (reading the comments):

```
#gallery {  
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;  
  white-space: nowrap; /* this is the trick */
}
#gallery img {  
  height: 200px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jQkHp/4/)**

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jQkHp/

I added a wrapper div around gallery:

```
#gallery {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gallery .gallery_img {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You will need to use some javascript to set the width of the gallery div for this to work properly (I'm only guessing at the width at the moment).

Edit - added some js to calculate the width of gallery based on the images inside it http://jsfiddle.net/jQkHp/1/

```
var galleryWidth = 0;

$('#gallery > img').each(function(){
  galleryWidth += $(this).width();
});

$('#gallery').css('width', galleryWidth);
```

Comment: the javascript does not work, as the images are not loaded when the JS is loaded.

Comment: Where are you getting the images from?

Answer (score 2):

Just add this in CSS

```
<style>
    #gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
#gallery img {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Let rest of code be as it is.

Comment: The simple way is usually the best!

Comment: where should I put this CSS to ? I tried both `#gallery` & `.gallery_img` , it does not work. I'm using Google Chrome, latest version.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle (same link as in the question) with `white-space`. You can try out. No half apple.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. try it let me know the result... :)

Comment: I have used same div and img structure as posted in question. and it works on both browser firefox and chrome

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the images in an unordered list within your containing div, with each image in it's own LI and then set them to display: inline-block in the css.

You'll need some way of scrolling through the images, of course, for which you could use some jquery.